# Positioning button to center for varying width and height in flex

Tags: apache-flex

I want to position my button always in center for any changing application width and height.

How to achieve it in mxml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the exact solution to position a button in center of stage for any changing stage width and height

```
button.x=(stage.stageWidth-button.width)/2;
button.y=(stage.stageHeight-button.height)/2;
```

Comment: The only problem with doing it this way is that it does not auto-update, unless you attach it to a resize function. Why not do `button.horizontalCenter = 0` and `button.verticalCenter = 0` instead? That will make sure they always stay updated, is cleaner code, and allows you to set it in the AS3, which is what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You want to position your button in the center of what?  Sometimes I think such code is better done in ActionScript as part of an updateDisplayList() method.  However, if you want to do this in MXML:

```
<buttonContainer id="container">
 <s:Button x="{container.width/2}" y="{container.height/2}" />
</buttonContainer>
```

This should work, conceptually, for any container.  Some containers make it a bit easier; such as a VGroup:

```
<s:VGroup horizontalAlign="Center" verticalAlign="middle">
     <s:Button />
</s:VGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the container of your `Button` has an absolute layout ([BasicLayout](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/layouts/BasicLayout.html)), it is as simple as using `UIcomponent`'s [horizontalCenter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#horizontalCenter) and [verticalCenter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#verticalCenter) properties:

```
<s:Group width="400" height="300">
    <s:Button horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0" />
</s:Group>
```

`BasicLayout` is the default layout of every Spark container. mx components don't have separate layout classes, but the concept is the same: positioning is absolute by default.

Comment: The purpose of a VerticalLayout is to position elements in a vertical line.  HorizontanalAlign and VerticalAlign are properties on the VerticalLayout class.  You seem to be saying that using these properties is against the purpose of the class.  I'm not sure I agree.  There is no "rule" that the first element of a VerticalLayout must start at position 0,0.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com You're absolutely right. I was deceived by the `x="{container.width/2}" y="{container.height/2}"` part in your VGroup example (which is probably a copy/paste error). I'll edit mine if you'll edit yours ;)

Comment: You're right; that was a copy and paste error on my part. Inside a VGroup the X and Y properties are ignored.

Comment: Thank you both, As said by "www.Flextras.com", I prefered to do it in actionscript rather than mxml and the code which helps to align center in actionscript: x=stage.stageWidth/2-somenumber. Is it correct?